Opening new Window only works once
In my code I implemented, that with a click of a button a new window should open. In this window I have some widgets along with a button to close the window again. This works just fine. The problem is, that after closing the window, I am not able to open it again. There is no Error message it just won't work anymore (along with some other buttons that worked before).
The problem is the folloing code:
global window_edit_point

.
.
.

def edit_point(i):
    global window_edit_point, entry_edit_x, entry_edit_y, entry_edit_z
    j = i
    root.update_idletasks()
    window_edit_point = tk.Tk()
    x_window = root.winfo_x() + (root.winfo_width() // 2) - (300 // 2)
    y_window = root.winfo_y() + (root.winfo_height() // 2) - (150 // 2)
    window_edit_point.geometry("300x150+"+str(x_window)+"+"+str(y_window))
    window_edit_point.configure(bg=bg_color)
    window_edit_point.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    window_edit_point.title("edit point")
    window_edit_point.update_idletasks()
    label_entry_edit_x = tk.Label(window_edit_point, text="x:", bg=bg_color)
    label_entry_edit_x.place(x=10, y=0)
    label_entry_edit_y = tk.Label(window_edit_point, text="y:", bg=bg_color)
    label_entry_edit_y.place(x=130, y=0)
    label_entry_edit_z = tk.Label(window_edit_point, text="z:", bg=bg_color)
    label_entry_edit_z.place(x=250, y=0)
    entry_edit_x = tk.Entry(window_edit_point, width=15)
    entry_edit_x.place(x=25, y=0)
    entry_edit_y = tk.Entry(window_edit_point, width=15)
    entry_edit_y.place(x=145, y=0)
    entry_edit_z = tk.Entry(window_edit_point, width=15)
    entry_edit_z.place(x=265, y=0)
    button_point_edit = tk.Button(window_edit_point, width=50, text="update point", command=lambda: update_point(j))
    button_point_edit.place(x=0, y=24)


def update_point(j):
    global window_edit_point, entry_edit_x, entry_edit_y, entry_edit_z
    x = int(entry_edit_x.get())
    y = int(entry_edit_y.get())
    z = int(entry_edit_z.get())
    list_points[j][0] = x
    list_points[j][1] = y
    list_points[j][2] = z
    draw_points()
    window_edit_point.destroy()

I've tried to isolate the problem, but there it worked fine:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.update_idletasks()

global new_win


def new_window():
    global new_win
    new_win = tk.Tk()
    button2 = tk.Button(new_win, text="close", command=close)
    button2.pack()


def close():
    global new_win
    new_win.destroy()


button1 = tk.Button(root, text="new_window", command=new_window)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()

Can someone please help me what I did different/wrong?

What draw_points() does? How did you set the command for the button that creates the new window, is it using lambda? are there other places in your code that use the global window_edit_point? It is challenging to refactor your problem with the given code without all the missing code parts that might be the cause for this.

It is better to provide a [mre] related to first example.

tk.Tk() is to create the root window. You could use tk.Toplevel() instead.
You can change:
window_edit_point = tk.Tk()

and
new_win = tk.Tk()

Changes
def edit_point(i):
    global window_edit_point, entry_edit_x, entry_edit_y, entry_edit_z
    j = i
    root.update_idletasks()
    window_edit_point = tk.Toplevel(root)
    x_window = root.winfo_x() + (root.winfo_width() // 2) - (300 // 2)

and

def new_window():
    global new_win
    new_win = tk.Toplevel(root)
    button2 = tk.Button(new_win, text="close", command=close)
    button2.pack()


Thanks for the suggestion, but I still have the same problem.

@CyberTigerhai Try this? You need to keep the root one, as it was.


The problem is, that after closing the window, I am not able to open
it again.

The problem can be fixed.

You don't need to declare the Global variable.
Move the close() function to the top inside the new_window()
function.

Snippet modified:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.update_idletasks()

 
def new_window():
    def close():     
        new_win.destroy()
     
    new_win = tk.Toplevel()
    button2 = tk.Button(new_win, text="close", command=close)
    button2.pack()


button1 = tk.Button(root, text="new_window", command=new_window)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()

Screenshot:

To open Toplevel window:

To close Toplevel window:

Change this:
def edit_point(i):
    .
    .
    .
    window_edit_point = tk.Toplevel() # change to Toplevel.

